# Sample proportion differing by more than 0.035 from p

Tags: statistics

In this question I've got the following pieces of information

$$n = 2500$$

$$p = 0.465$$

I need to estimate the probability that the proportion $\hat p$ in the sample differs by more than $0.035$ from $p$

Comment: What have you tried? From the context do you guess you're might be expected to use a normal approximation? Are you studying hypothesis testing? Confidence intervals? Our rules about providing 'context' are not _just_ to keep you from using us as a 'do my homework' service. We can't read you mind about what your difficulty is.

Answer (score 0):

***Further Comment:*** My *guess* is you're supposed to start with

$$Z = \frac{\hat p - p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}} \stackrel{aprx}{\sim }\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$$

so that $P(|Z| > c) = P(|\hat p - p| > c\sqrt{p(1-p)/n})$ can be approximated using normal tables. If you don't know $p$, it might help to observe that $p(1-p) \le 1/4.$